# Obtener urls de una busqueda de Google con PHP

Tags: php, url, curl

Lo que tengo que hacer es obtener las urls (5 aprox.) a partir de una búsqueda de google. Es decir;
yo busco la palabra gato en google y quiero obtener los 5 primeros links de los resultados que aparecen y guardarlos en una bbdd.

He intentado mediante cURL obtener la página en cuestión y con el string que me devuelve a través de una expresión regular buscar los links. Sin embargo no me vale porque también coge los links de maps, imagenes, etc...

Se os ocurre o sabéis algún método mejor?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Las preguntas que están basadas en opiniones es probable que acaben cerradas.

Comment: Por cierto, te recomiendo que no uses expresiones regulares para encontrar elementos en el DOM de un documento HTML. PHP puede trabajar con el [DOM de un documento HTML](https://www.php.net/es/dom) de manera nativa y mucho más sencilla que usando expresiones regulares. Te doy dos pistas para que lo hagas correctamente: [`DOMXPath::query()`](https://www.php.net/es/domxpath.query) y `//div[@class='g']//a[@ping]//h3/..`.